# Can every element of an algebraic field extension, $E \subseteq F$ be represented as $f(s)$, where $s$ is another member and $f(x) \in F[x]$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Specifically, could every member of $E$ be generated by one element $s$, by evaluating different polynomials of $s$ with coefficients in $F$?

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I should've specified that

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question:  I thought it said "$s$ generates $E$" as a fact, not "can there be one single element [always]."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $F \to E$ is an infinite algebraic extension then any element $s \in E$ generates at best a finite subextension $F[s]$ of $E$, so $E$ will never be generated by one element. If $F \to E$ is a finite algebraic extension then a necessary and sufficient condition is given by the [primitive element theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem): it is necessary and sufficient that there be finitely may intermediate extensions between $E$ and $F$.

This condition in particular always holds for finite [separable extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension), which is the most commonly used special case of the primitive element theorem. For example, it follows that every finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ (that is, number fields) is generated by one element.

*Example.* Consider the extension $\mathbb{F}_p(x^p, y^p) \to \mathbb{F}_p(x, y)$. This is a purely inseparable extension of degree $p^2$. Any element $f \in \mathbb{F}_p(x, y)$ has the property that $f^p \in \mathbb{F}_p(x^p, y^p)$, and consequently generates an extension of $\mathbb{F}_p(x^p, y^p)$ of degree at most $p$; hence $f$ cannot generate the entire extension.

Comment: Thank you, I'd thought that, but I wasn't sure if my justification was enough